# Where can I deploy a JavaScript app for collaborative testing?

Tags: development, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm developing a new ArcGIS Server JavaScript application, and I'd like to show the progress to the client, so he can provide feedback as I develop it.

The application consists of an Index.html file, a *.JS file containing my code, a *.CSS file for the styles and a *.JSON file containing the map configuration. I don't have access to a public-facing web server in my organisation.

**Are there any sites (preferably free) where I can upload my files, so he can run and test the application?**

I looked at [github](https://github.com/) but from what I can gather it's a *repository*, rather than a place where my application will actually *run* (eg, test the Identify tool and verify that it works) - please let me know if that's not correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Github has [Github pages](http://pages.github.com) if you want to host a small website.
[Source control and issues tracking](https://github.com/features/projects) would be two features that will be helpful in your case imho.

Otherwise, you could also use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), but then you need to host the JSON file somewhere else.

Update: You could also use [Amazon AWS](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html?key=my-free-website) to host it (but a bit more complicated to setup).

Comment: JSFiddle + Dropbox would be my choice.

Answer (score 2):

Any free web hosting site can deploy (run) your javascript app

http://www.110mb.com/

ArcGIS Javascript Example

http://mapperz.110mb.com/GMAP/Drive_Time/index.html

Though if your are developing javascript application then it might be beneficial for your company to have public internet access location for your clients to login and view the work they are paying for.

Comment: "it might be beneficial for your company to have public internet access location" - I hear ya. Working on it!

Comment: +1: even though 110mb is currently not accepting free registrations, i will be waiting to open mine.